# How to put the percentage of use of each core from cpu

Tags: scripting, monitoring, system-information, cpu-usage

I use the Zabbix Server to monitor my environment.
The metrics used by Zabbix to view the CPU are too confusing, so I would like to simplify.

Is there a way to get the percentage of use of each core cpu?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `top` which is a real time system monitor. `top` splits CPU usage between user, system processes and `nice` processes, we want the sum of the three which is what the `awk` command below is doing. So, we can run `top` in `b`atch mode which allows us to parse its output. However, as explained [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=174619), the 1st iteration of `top -b` returns the percentages since boot, we therefore need at least two iterations (`-n 2`) to get the current percentage. To speed things up, you can set the `d`elay between iterations to `0.01`:

```
$ top -bn 2 -d 0.01 | grep '^%Cpu' | awk '{print "CPU"NR, $2+$4+$6"%"}'
CPU1 14.6%
CPU2 25%
```